# Flutter: row cross axis expand

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Is there any way to give a specific widget the height of the highest widget in the row? I don't want to stretch the row on the cross axis. I just want all widgets to have the height of the highest widget.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Sure ! Simply wrap your Row into an `IntrinsicHeight`

```
IntrinsicHeight(
  child: Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    children: <Widget>[],
  ),
);
```

Comment: Great solution but keep in mind: *"This class is relatively expensive. Avoid using it where possible."* - according to the docs.

Comment: Frequently an alternative would be to place the widgets in a Stack and wrap all widgets with a Positioned beside the largest one.

Comment: But what if i have this single item that i want to stretch, which is `align-self: stretch` in css without using `height: double.infinity` ?

Comment: Thank you, Remi!

Answer (score 6):

There are a number of things to consider.

#### Parent of Row Constrained

`IntrinsicHeight` would only work [if](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicHeight-class.html) "unlimited height is available". Conversely, if the parent of the `Row` is constrained, it would **not** work [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/f0d917f3b42881c24977b37e4e2111f9?null_safety=true).

- If what you want to do is extend the widgets height to match the parent simply do:

```dart
Row(
 crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
 ...
)
```

It will make all widgets the same height, even if you set row's children height unequal. It will ignore children's height and will not make the other widgets the same as the tallest.

#### Parent of Row Unconstrained

- If you know the height of the tallest widget beforehand, simply constraint the parent of the `Row` with that height with `SizedBox`.
- If not, but you know the aspect ratio, use `AspectRatio` instead it is a much cheaper widget.

```dart
AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: 2, // try diff numbers
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
)
```

- If you still don't know any of that which is rarely the case there are a few other options to implement the layout by hand with `LayoutBuilder` or creating a new widget.
- If none of that work use `IntrinsicHeight` as parent of Row as a last resort since it is supposedly an expensive widget. You can try measuring performance (not scientific because you would need a real phisical device):

```dart
main() async {
  testWidgets('test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    final Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch()..start();
    for (int index = 0; index < 1000; index += 1) {
      await tester.pumpWidget( MyApp());
    }
    timer.stop();
    debugPrint('Time taken: ${timer.elapsedMilliseconds}ms');
  });
}
```

### Summary

It is unlikely that you need to match siblings widgets' height to a single one with an unknown height. If that is really the case, the widget must be first rendered and notified like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58000495/how-to-get-child-widget-size-for-animation-values-in-parent) or indirectly with `IntrinsicHeight`.

**EDIT**

Option 6: If you know the width, you can use Stack.

```dart
Container(
        color: Colors.grey,
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(child: Text("T", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 90),),color: Colors.green, width: 200,),
            Positioned.fill(left: 100,child: Container(child: Text("TTTTT", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),color: Colors.blue)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Option 7: If you want to use `ValueNotifier` `ValueListenableBuilder` `GlobalKey`.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  GlobalKey _rowKey = GlobalKey();
  final ValueNotifier<double> _rowHeight = ValueNotifier<double>(-1);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback(
        (_) => _rowHeight.value = _rowKey.currentContext!.size!.height);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.grey,
        child: ValueListenableBuilder<double>(
          valueListenable: _rowHeight,
          builder: (_, __, ___) => Row(
            key: _rowKey,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: Text(
                  "T",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 90),
                ),
                color: Colors.green,
                width: 200,
              ),
              Container(
                  height: (_rowHeight.value<0)? null : _rowHeight.value,
                  child: Container(
                      child: Text(
                        "TTTTT",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                      color: Colors.blue)),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```