# How to get child widget size for animation values in parent

Tags: flutter, dart

While flutter is growing, there are much recommendations and "ways how to". I am not sure what is correct as i am really new to the framework.

Say, i have the following code (hardly reduced):

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return GestureDetector(
    // heights are needed here for animation values
      child: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Positioned(
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        bottom: value,
        child: Column( // overall height
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(height: 60),  // 1
            Container(height: 150), // 2
            Container(height: 200),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ));
}
```

In the `GestureDetector` i am animating some widget actions, depending on different heights of it`s children.

The `height` of children `//1` and `//2` (and third) will be set hardcoded while developing, but, because there are several such elements and custom widgets, i want to get them automatically. Later on, this is better maintenable all in all, because mostly every widget anywhere has some animations.

So, i can use `GlobalKey`, or maybe `BoxConstraints`, but - all in all - what is the cheapest way to do that if building as a custom widget?

To close the question: in `GestureDetector` i am able to rebuild after the initial layout is done and after every rebuild.

I am just not sure about which way is safe and has minimum costs (having those widgets several times in the code).

About `//1` and `//2`: `//1` is the initial animation `begin:` value, `//2` is a value in the middle to stop, `// overall height` is animation `end:` value. Just to explain.

At least: i am using `states_rebuilder` inside all of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We just can get the size of a widget after it's rendered unless it is a constant.
We can use ValueNotifier to send the size of the child after it rendered.

Here is the completed example for it.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  ValueNotifier<Size> _size = ValueNotifier<Size>(Size(0, 0));

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("example")
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ValueListenableBuilder(
              builder: (BuildContext context, Size value, Widget child) {
                return Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Height of the child: ${value.height}'),
                    Text('Width of the child: ${value.width}'),
                    SizeTrackingWidget(
                      child: Container(
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.4,
                        width:  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.3,
                        color: Colors.red
                      ),
                      sizeValueNotifier: _size,
                    )
                  ],
                );
              },
              valueListenable: _size,
              child: null,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class SizeTrackingWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  Widget child;
  ValueNotifier<Size> sizeValueNotifier;
  SizeTrackingWidget({Key key, @required this.sizeValueNotifier, @required this.child}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _SizeTrackingWidgetState createState() => _SizeTrackingWidgetState();
}

class _SizeTrackingWidgetState extends State<SizeTrackingWidget> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){
      _getSize();
    });
  }

  _getSize() {
    RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject();
    widget.sizeValueNotifier.value = renderBox.size;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.child;
  }
}
```

Comment: This sounds interesting! Thank you very much, i will implement this for better understanding.

Comment: This will only work if the value (will some time) had changed? My value `heigt` in this cases is hardcoded, may never be changed, but i want to get `height` via code for easier maintenance instead of having several constants for all of them.

Comment: It will work in both case. If you set the height equal 200, after it is rendered, it will also return the height equal 200. You should, notice, this will return real size of widget when it goes to the screen and rendered.

Comment: Ok, i will implement this the next days. Thank you

Comment: This solves a few other considerations as well, so i would like to mark this as the accepted answer. Thank you, a really good job!

Comment: Why are you extending `StatefulWidget` with `SizeTrackingWidget` instead of using `_size.value`?

Comment: But i didn't found a way to listen to several values and added a *feauture request* https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40906

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by the accepted answer of @Thang Mai I made a similar stateless solution:

```
class ChildSizeNotifier extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget Function(BuildContext context, Size size, Widget child) builder;
  final Widget child;
  ChildSizeNotifier({
    Key? key,
    required this.builder,
    this.child,
  }) : super(key: key) {}

  @override
  State<ChildSizeNotifier> createState() => _ChildSizeNotifierState();
}

class _ChildSizeNotifierState extends State<ChildSizeNotifier> {
 final ValueNotifier<Size> _notifier = ValueNotifier(const Size(0, 0));

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _notifier.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(
      (_) {
        notifier.value = (context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox).size;
      },
    );
    return ValueListenableBuilder(
      valueListenable: notifier,
      builder: builder,
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

Use it like this

```
ChildSizeNotifier(
  builder: (context, size, child) {
    // size is the size of the text
    return Text(size.height > 50 ? 'big' : 'small');
  },
)
```

Comment: Notifiers need to be disposed of when the widget is distracted(resource cleanup). I changed the widget to stateful so that I can dispose of the Size Notifier in the dispose override.