# ValueListenableBuilder: listen to more than one value

Tags: flutter

I am using `ValueListenableBuilder` to watch some values in several animated custom widgets. Those are using several values, based on their children sizes, to animate depending actions.

My problem is *listening to more than one value*. I have to nest them.

The following is a reduced example to explain:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final ValueNotifier<double> _height1 = ValueNotifier<double>(40);
  final ValueNotifier<double> _height2 = ValueNotifier<double>(120);
  final ValueNotifier<double> _height3 = ValueNotifier<double>(200);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, double h1, Widget child) {
        return ValueListenableBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, double h2, Widget child) {
            return ValueListenableBuilder(
                builder: (BuildContext context, double h3, Widget child) {
                  return GestureDetector(
                    // i am using h1, h2 and h3 here ...
                    child: Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Positioned(
                          left: 0,
                          right: 0,
                          bottom: value,
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Container(height: _height1.value),
                              Container(height: _height2.value),
                              Container(height: _height3.value),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
                valueListenable: _height3,
                child: null);
          },
          valueListenable: _height2,
          child: null,
        );
      },
      valueListenable: _height1,
      child: null,
    );
  }
}
```

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40906#issuecomment-533383128 give a short hint to `Listenable.merge`, but I have no idea how to use this.

Comment: Have you read the API description of Listenable.merge? What exactly is unclear.

Comment: If the 3 heights in your example can change independently then each `Container` should be directly wrapped in an independent `ValueListenableBuilder` and no nesting is needed, i.e. `ValueListenableBuilder( builder: (BuildContext context, double h1, Widget child) { return Container(height: _height1.value);  }, valueListenable: _height1, child: null)`

Comment: Just a thought, in an example like this, you're probably far better off if you create a custom `ValueNotifier` by extending it; in your case e.g. of a custom class with three properties, `height1`, `height2`, `height3`. Then use a single `ValueListenableBuilder()` which listens to your custom `ValueNotifier`. Check [the video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s-ZG-jS5QHQ&t=70s) for details on how to extend `ValueNotifier` to create a custom one.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There's nothing built-in.

You *could* use `Listenable.merge`. But it has flaws:

- it's not "safe" (you can forget to listen to a value)
- it's not ideal performance-wise (since we're recreating a Listenable on every build)

Instead, we can use composition: we can write a stateless widget that combines 2+ ValueListenableBuilders into one, and use that.

It'd be used this way:

```dart
ValueListenable<SomeValue> someValueListenable;
ValueListenable<AnotherValue> anotherValueListenable;

ValueListenableBuilder2<SomeValue, AnotherValue>(
  someValueListenable,
  anotherValueListenable,
  builder: (context, someValue, anotherValue, child) {
    return Text('$someValue $anotherValue');
  },
  child: ...,
);
```

Where the code of such `ValueListenableBuilder2` is:

```dart
class ValueListenableBuilder2<A, B> extends StatelessWidget {
 ValueListenableBuilder2(
    this.first,
    this.second, {
    Key key,
    this.builder,
    this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final ValueListenable<A> first;
  final ValueListenable<B> second;
  final Widget child;
  final Widget Function(BuildContext context, A a, B b, Widget child) builder;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder<A>(
      valueListenable: first,
      builder: (_, a, __) {
        return ValueListenableBuilder<B>(
          valueListenable: second,
          builder: (context, b, __) {
            return builder(context, a, b, child);
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:** null safety version:

```dart
class ValueListenableBuilder2<A, B> extends StatelessWidget {
  const ValueListenableBuilder2({
    required this.first,
    required this.second,
    Key? key,
    required this.builder,
    this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final ValueListenable<A> first;
  final ValueListenable<B> second;
  final Widget? child;
  final Widget Function(BuildContext context, A a, B b, Widget? child) builder;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => ValueListenableBuilder<A>(
        valueListenable: first,
        builder: (_, a, __) {
          return ValueListenableBuilder<B>(
            valueListenable: second,
            builder: (context, b, __) {
              return builder(context, a, b, child);
            },
          );
        },
      );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I just saw this answer this moment. I had read it 2 times, but i have to look again next time. But, using this or `GlobalKey`, `GlobalKey` feels at least the better way (should be measured then). What do you think compared to Keys? Makes sense to go this way?

Comment: What's the relationship between your question/this answer and GlobalKey?

Comment: A little bit complicated. I just want to have those heights when animating via `GestureDetector`. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58000495/how-to-get-child-widget-size-for-animation-values-in-parent) gives `ValueListenableBuilder` as a (good) solution. But, it seems to be to much for this usecase. I just wanted to reduce unneeded `GlobalKey`s; but this got now more complex in my opinion.

Comment: Ok, i understand. This feels like the most acceptable answer to the question. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 21):

You cannot use ValueListenableBuilder with Listenable.merge because merge returns only a Listenable and no ValueListenable and ValueListenableBuilder expects a Value Changenotifier. 
You can use AnimatedBuilder instead which despite its name is just a ListenableBuilder.

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final ValueNotifier<double> _height1 = ValueNotifier<double>(40);
  final ValueNotifier<double> _height2 = ValueNotifier<double>(120);
  final ValueNotifier<double> _height3 = ValueNotifier<double>(200);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: Listenable.merge([_height1, _height2, _height3]),
      builder: (BuildContext context, _) {
        return GestureDetector(
          // i am using h1, h2 and h3 here ...
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Positioned(
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                bottom: value,
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(height: _height1.value),
                    Container(height: _height2.value),
                    Container(height: _height3.value),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this was my first thought, too. But it just works in the linter. It errors. But, i will have a look again. Thank you.

Comment: `builder: (BuildContext context, _) {` - where is the `value` now?

Comment: As explained here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40906 this is to much spaghetti to me and therefore not an acceptable answer. For me, the initial feature request takes place.

Comment: You don't *have* to use `AnimatedBuilder`. You can use [ListenableBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListenableBuilder-class.html) along with `Listenable.merge()`. You can also call/construct `Listenable.merge()` outside of the `build()` method so it isn't built every time.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of messing with the builder simply wrap the listenables using a dummy Valuelistenable and the Listenable.merge
This ends up with minor overhead but far simpler code.
Please keep in mind that since it doesn't check the value of each listenable it might be slightly less inefficient if the listeners are being called with same value. Normally the builder would have ignored the notification because the value would be the same.
You could easily keep track of each individual value and compare before toggling the val, but i haven't seen any real performance issue so i didn't bother for now.

Using this code the 2nd argument of the builder will toggle between true/false to tell the ValueListenableBuilder that there has been a change. So simply ignore it.
You can always perform your functionality from your passed listenables

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class ValuesNotifier implements ValueListenable<bool> {
  final List<ValueListenable> valueListenables;
  late final Listenable listenable;
  bool val = false;
  ValuesNotifier(this.valueListenables) {
    listenable = Listenable.merge(valueListenables);
    listenable.addListener(onNotified);
  }

  @override
  void addListener(VoidCallback listener) {
    listenable.addListener(listener);
  }

  @override
  void removeListener(VoidCallback listener) {
    listenable.removeListener(listener);
  }

  @override
  bool get value => val;

  void onNotified() {
    val = !val;
  }
}
```

Example usage

```
ValueListenableBuilder(
    valueListenable: ValuesNotifier([
      valueNotifier1,
      valueNotifier2,
    ]),
    builder: (_, __, ___) => Visibility(
      visible: valueNotifier1.value,
      child: Text(valueNotifier2.value),
    ))
```

Answer (score 4):

I too ran into same problem and had to use nested ValueListenableBuilder widgets. But then I wrapped whole logic inside a custom MultiValueListenableBuilder widget and published it as a Flutter package.

Here is link to my package: https://pub.dev/packages/multi_value_listenable_builder

Using this package you can provide a list of ValueListenable and their latest values will be available in same order in builder function. Here is an example.

```dart
    MultiValueListenableBuider(
    // Add all ValueListenables here.
    valueListenables: [
        listenable0,
        listenable1,
        listenable2,
        .
        .
        listenableN
    ],
    builder: (context, values, child) {
        // Get the updated value of each listenable
        // in values list.
        return YourWidget(
            values.elementAt(0),
            values.elementAt(1),
            values.elementAt(2),
            .
            .
            values.elementAt(N),
            child: child // Optional child.
        );
    },
    child: YourOptionalChildWidget(),
)
```

Comment: It's also worth noting that there is [another package](https://pub.dev/packages/property_change_notifier) that serves this same function but for cases where the items being listened to are class properties. For example, `PropertyChangeConsumer<MyHeights, String>( properties: ['height1', 'height2','height3'], builder: (context, model, properties) { ... },`

Answer (score 3):

Multiple values can be listened, if those are encapsulated as a class, So you could listen to the data type of the class and access the members inside it, so any changes made to it are reflected to the listener,

Comment: would you please give some example, thanks?

Comment: I would simply pass a Model/data class instead of a primitive data type, So that class would have can have multiple member values

Comment: I understand your idea but feel challenging in implementing it. If you can provide some generic examples would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A "Flutter-like" solution is to copy the existing ValueListenableBuilder code and add support for another listenable param. Do this for as many ValueListenableBuilders as needed (i.e. ValueListenableBuilder3, ValueListenableBuilder4...).

For more than 3 ValueListenableBuilders, it might be easier to use a ChangeNotifier instead.

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

typedef ValueWidgetBuilder2<T, T2> = Widget Function(
    BuildContext context, T value1, T2 value2, Widget? child);

class ValueListenableBuilder2<T, T2> extends StatefulWidget {
  const ValueListenableBuilder2({
    Key? key,
    required this.valueListenable1,
    required this.valueListenable2,
    required this.builder,
    this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final ValueListenable<T> valueListenable1;
  final ValueListenable<T2> valueListenable2;
  final ValueWidgetBuilder2<T, T2> builder;
  final Widget? child;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _ValueListenableBuilder2State<T, T2>();
}

class _ValueListenableBuilder2State<T, T2>
    extends State<ValueListenableBuilder2<T, T2>> {
  late T value1;
  late T2 value2;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    value1 = widget.valueListenable1.value;
    value2 = widget.valueListenable2.value;
    widget.valueListenable1.addListener(_valueChanged1);
    widget.valueListenable2.addListener(_valueChanged2);
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(ValueListenableBuilder2<T, T2> oldWidget) {
    if (oldWidget.valueListenable1 != widget.valueListenable1 &&
        oldWidget.valueListenable2 != widget.valueListenable2) {
      oldWidget.valueListenable1.removeListener(_valueChanged1);
      value1 = widget.valueListenable1.value;
      widget.valueListenable1.addListener(_valueChanged1);

      oldWidget.valueListenable2.removeListener(_valueChanged2);
      value2 = widget.valueListenable2.value;
      widget.valueListenable2.addListener(_valueChanged2);
    }
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.valueListenable1.removeListener(_valueChanged1);
    widget.valueListenable2.removeListener(_valueChanged2);
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _valueChanged1() {
    setState(() {
      value1 = widget.valueListenable1.value;
    });
  }

  void _valueChanged2() {
    setState(() {
      value2 = widget.valueListenable2.value;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.builder(context, value1, value2, widget.child);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ive done recursive function to make behaviour you want, I am not sure its the best answer but you will probably like it.

```
class _MultiValueListenableBuilder extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<ValueNotifier> valueListenables;
  final Widget Function(BuildContext, List values) builder;
  const _MultiValueListenableBuilder({Key? key,
    required this.valueListenables,
    required this.builder,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _create(valueListenables, context);
  }

  Widget _create(List<ValueNotifier> notifiers, BuildContext context,) {
    if(notifiers.isEmpty) {
      return builder(context, valueListenables.map((e) => e.value).toList());
    }
    final copy = [...notifiers];
    final notifier = copy.removeAt(0);
    return ValueListenableBuilder(
      valueListenable: notifier,
      builder: (_, __, ___) => _create(copy, _),
      child: _create(copy, context),
    );
  }
}
```

I also created test widget to check if everything works as it is supposed

```
class _MultiTest extends StatefulWidget {
  const _MultiTest({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MultiTestState createState() => _MultiTestState();
}

class _MultiTestState extends State<_MultiTest> {
  final notifier1 = ValueNotifier('otherwise');
  final notifier2 = ValueNotifier('look');
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        _MultiValueListenableBuilder(
          valueListenables: [notifier1, notifier2],
          builder: (_, values) => Text(values.fold<String>('', (pv, e) => pv + ' ' + e), style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20),),
        ),
        MyTextButton(
          title: 'do',
          onPressed: () {
            notifier1.value = notifier1.value + 'otherwise';
            notifier2.value = notifier2.value + 'look';
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Feel free to ask any question I probably missed something up.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to achieve similar goals as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67668407/2159867) i.e. without nesting BuildContext

I have left the class as abstract in my case, but, it can receive a callback function as argument as an alternative.

```dart
abstract class AllMultiValueListeners extends StatelessWidget {
  /// List of [ValueListenable]s to listen to.
  final List<ValueListenable> valueListenables;

  const AllMultiValueListeners({Key key, @required this.valueListenables})
      : super(key: key);

  ValueListenableBuilder getListenableBuilder(int index) {
    List<dynamic> values = [];
    return ValueListenableBuilder(
        valueListenable: valueListenables.elementAt(index),
        builder: (BuildContext context, value, Widget child) {
          for (int i = 0; i < valueListenables.length; i++) {
            if (values.length <= i) {
              values.add(valueListenables.elementAt(i).value);
            } else {
              values[i] = valueListenables.elementAt(i).value;
            }
          }

          if (index == valueListenables.length - 1) {
            return valuesChangedBuilder(context, values, child);
          } else {
            return getListenableBuilder(index + 1);
          }
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return getListenableBuilder(0);
  }

  /// override this method to rebuild something when there the one or more values have changed
  Widget valuesChangedBuilder(
    BuildContext ctx,
    List<dynamic> values,
    Widget child,
  );
}
```